# Ajax Call and Response is not working when page loads first time

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, ajax-request

I am doing some Ajax call through Jquery Ready function. And After backend processing I am setting few variables in Session. When back to my Same JSP Page, I am trying to print those variables BUT when page loads first time, these variables are coming empty. If i reload page, I am able to see Variables'values. I am not sure Where I am wrong.

Ajax Call on JSP

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var myToy = 'B';

    var url="/myBuysAjaxCall.ac?&myToy="+myToy;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        AJAX = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
        if(ms_xmlhttp) {
            AJAX = new ActiveXObject(ms_xmlhttp);
        } else {
            var versions=["Msxml2.XMLHTTP.7.0", "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0", "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0", "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0", "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"];
            for(var i=0; i<versions.length; i++) {
                try {
                    AJAX = new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);
                    if(AJAX) {
                        ms_xmlhttp = versions[i];
                    }
                } catch(e) {
                    //do nothing. go to next version and try it.
                }
            }
        }
    }

    AJAX.onreadystatechange = processMyToy;

    AJAX.open("GET", url, true);
    console.log("Ajax call made..");
    AJAX.send(null);

 });

function processMyToy() {
    if (AJAX.readyState == 4) { // Complete
        if (AJAX.status == 200) { // OK response

            var returnedValue = AJAX.responseText; 
            console.log("Something came in Response ");

            var obj1FromSession= '<c:out value="${obj1FromSession}"/>';
            var obj2FromSession= '<c:out value="${obj2FromSession}"/>';
            var obj3FromSession= '<c:out value="${obj3FromSession}"/>';

            console.log(obj1FromSession);
            console.log(obj2FromSession);
            console.log(obj3FromSession);

        }
    }

});
```

Back end Code

```
public void loadandProcessMyToy() throws Exception{

    Context contextObj = ContextHelper.getContext();
    String myToy = (String) contextObj.getObjectFromRequest("myToy");

    If Condition{

        String obj1FromSession="Hello 1";
        String obj2FromSession="Hello 2";
        String obj3FromSession="Hello 3";

        ContextHelper.getContext().setObjectInSession("obj1FromSession",obj1FromSession);
        ContextHelper.getContext().setObjectInSession("obj2FromSession",obj2FromSession);
        ContextHelper.getContext().setObjectInSession("obj3FromSession",obj3FromSession);

    }

}
```

**NOTE :-** When Page loads first time, It is coming as Empty in Ajax Response Section. On Reload of page ( through F5 ), It is printing Hello1, Hello2.. as expected.

I want to see values on first time load only. Please help.

Comment: try to make ajax call synchronous

Comment: why not use [jquery's ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)?

Comment: can u plz write some specific sample code for reference. Would be grateful. :)